# angular-ui ui-router modal state.onExit ... change to new state happens too fast

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'd like to build a simple "Are you sure to leave ok cancel" modal between state1 and state2. Therefor I use the ui-router example (How To: Open a dialog/modal at a certain state) with onExit within state1. The modal appears but the state change to state2 happens before the modal is closed.

How can a stay in state1, have the modal, press ok or cancel and the change to state2 happens after closing modal?

Thx ahead for any hints

Answer (score 1):

You can use '$stateChangeStart' even on the root scope like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams) {
   event.preventDefault();
   showModal().then(function() {
       $state.go(toState, toParams);
   });
 });
```

Comment: Using too many listeners is bad. That should be done only as a last resort but every time I read angular related posts people always say just use a scope.on(). All listeners run every time there's an event so having 100 of them means you have an equivalent of 100 if() conditions. You'd be surprised how fast that number goes up to the 100s especially when you have 3rd party libs.

Answer (score 0):

`onExit` is the wrong place to do that. It is called when the state has already started exiting.

You can implement your modal like this instead:

Show the modal when user performs the exit action (like a button click) but do not call state change yet.

If user clicks **Ok** button in the modal then call `$state.go('state2')`

Else if user clicks **Cancel**, just hide the modal. User will remain in state1!

Comment: But what if the user leaves the state by some other means, like say there's a main navigation bar and the user changes to another state by using the navigation bar? (It'd be nice to have a confirm modal like 'You have unsaved changes, are you sure you want to leave this page?') Is there a "catch all" way of doing it?

Comment: @DecadeMoon in that case you can use State Change Listener and use event.preventDefault() to stop state change: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events